Running dragonfly pipeline command not returning results
I'm working on porting a Redis cluster to DragonflyDB and running into some problems with commands that I used to be able to run that aren't working anymore. In particular, I run a large number of pipeline commands. In the Redis Cluster these worked fine, but in Dragonfly I'm running into a limitation and I'm not sure why.
I'm essentially building a pipeline with anywhere up to 500,000 smembers command using the python redis.RedisCluster client (part of py-redis). As I mentioned, this works just fine for me using a Redis cluster on the backend, running in AWS ElastiCache. However, running in an emulated cluster on Dragonfly and it's not working for me. The code works fine, but I'm running into limitations when I get up to about 150,000 smembers commands in the pipeline. Is there a setting on the DragonflyDB Server somewhere that I need to change?
I'm running dragonflydb 1.22.2 in Docker.
